# Terraform state - change resource position

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, subnet

In one of our accounts a long time ago AWS private subnets were created. There are no matching public subnets and no resources in these private subnets. So below, `aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]` and `aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]` are the empty subnets

```
aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[3]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[4]
```

The subnets were created using terrform exactly as below:

```
 resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
      count      = length(split(",", var.private_subnets))
      cidr_block = element(split(",", var.private_subnets), count.index)
```

where `var.private_subnets` is a string containing our 5 different CIDR blocks.

I want to tidy this up but I tried removing the first two CIDR blocks from the string, but it still tries to recreate them, because it wants to change:

`aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]` to `aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]`,

`aws_subnet.private_subnets[3]` to `aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]`,

`aws_subnet.private_subnets[4]` to `aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]`

I don't want this to happen as then I would need to redeploy all our EC2s again in the new subnets. So what is the best way around this? Is it to remove them from the state, with:

`terraform state rm aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]`

and then change them with:

`terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]'`

I haven't worked a lot with the state and breaking this could cause a lot of problems, so just want to be sure. Or would a better bet be to delete them manually in AWS and then run the terraform again? - I'm not sure if this would cause the same problem that I currently have

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the source collection in a way that affects which objects belong to which indices then indeed you will need to use a strategy like `terraform state mv` to explain to Terraform how the index assignments have changed.

In your case it seems like that would be the following:

```
terraform state rm 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]'
terraform state rm 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[3]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[4]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]'
```

The ordering of these operations is important because Terraform cannot track two different objects at the same address, and so we need to always free up the target index before moving another instance into it.

---

It seems like your `var.private_subnets` here is a string containing a comma-separated list of CIDR blocks. In modern Terraform it would typically be better to declare this as a set of strings -- so that each CIDR block is a separate element -- and then use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) rather than [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) so that Terraform will track the instances by the CIDR block strings themselves, rather than by their arbitrary positions in a list.

```
variable "private_subnets" {
  type = set(string)
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  for_each = var.private_subnets

  cidr_block = each.value
}
```

This change will *also* require some migration work using `terraform state mv`, so since you'll be doing that work anyway it might be beneficial to make this change at the same time and thus avoid doing migration twice to get to the modern idiom.

You didn't include in your question the actual values of the CIDR addresses, so I'm just going to assume sequential addresses like `10.x.0.0/16` where "x" is the same as the index. Under that scheme, your migration would look something like this instead:

```
terraform state rm 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]'
terraform state rm 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets["10.2.0.0/16"]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[3]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets["10.3.0.0/16"]'
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.private_subnets[4]' 'aws_subnet.private_subnets["10.4.0.0/16"]'
```

Notice that in this case the new addresses have instance keys that are strings containing the actual CIDR prefixes rather than being integer positions in the list.

That means that they no longer have any inherent order and Terraform will understand that if you add something new to the set it means to create a new subnet, and if you remove an item from the set it means to remove the corresponding subnet. If you remove CIDR prefixes in the future, after doing this one-time migration, you won't need to `terraform state mv` to fix up the positions because they no longer *have* specific positions.